# Remove gridline in Angular charts. Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular charts but I can't seem to remove the gridlines! This is my code:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
  chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="false" responsive="true" 
  chart-click="onClick" scaleShowVerticalLines= "false">
</canvas>
```

My js file looks like this

```
$scope.labels = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mars", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                 "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
$scope.series = ['2015', '2014'];
$scope.data = 
[
  [80, 85, 90, 85, 90, 97, 90, 80, 90, 96, 97, 99]
];

$scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
  console.log(points, evt);
};
```

How do I remove the lines?

Answer (score 1):

Add chart-options to your html:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
chart-labels="labels" chart-legend="false" responsive="true" 
chart-click="onClick" scaleShowVerticalLines= "false"
chart-options="options">
</canvas>
```

and add chart-options to your js file. It would look like this:

```
$scope.options = {scales: {
                     xAxes: [{
                          gridLines: {
                               display: false
                          }
                       }],
                     yAxes: [{
                          gridLines: {
                               display:false
                          }
                       }]
                     }
                  };
```